# Ошибка в доступе к открытому методу закрытой переменной

Tags: java

Повторяю в точности код из книги Шилдта

```
class MyClass { // Сравнение видов доступа public и private
private int alpha; // закрытый доступ
public int beta; // открытый доступ
int gamma; // .тип доступа по умолчанию (по сути, public)

/* Методы доступа к переменной alpha. Члены класса могут
обращаться к закрытым членам того же класса.
*/
void setAlpha(int а) { // открытый метод setAlpha
    alpha = а;
}
int getAlpha() {  // открытый метод getAlpha

    return alpha;
}
```

}

```
class AccessDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyClass оb = new MyClass();

    /* Доступ к переменной alpha возможен только с помощью
    специально предназначенных для этой цели методов. */

    ob.setAlpha(-99);
    System.out.println("ob.alpha: " + ob.getAlpha());
    // Обратиться к переменной alpha так, как показано ниже, нельзя
    // ob.alpha = 10; // Ошибка: alpha - закрытая переменная!
    // Следующие обращения вполне допустимы, так как
    // переменные beta и gamma являются открытыми
    оb.beta = 88;
    ob.gamma = 99;
    System.out.println("ob.gamma: " + ob.beta);
}
```

}

- получаю ошибки:

Error (26, 9) java: cannot find symbol. symbol: variable ob. location: class AccessDemo

Error (27, 43) java: cannot find symbol. symbol: variable ob. location: class AccessDemo

Error (33, 9) java: cannot find symbol. symbol: variable ob. location: class AccessDemo

Error (34, 43) java: cannot find symbol. symbol: variable ob. location: class AccessDemo

Какой символ он не может найти? Если добавить/объявить переменную `ob` как подсказывает intellij idea - будет ошибка на методе `ob.setAlpha(-99);`

> Прошу подсказать чего не хватает в коде для работоспособности.

Comment: У вас в переменной ob (о кириллицой написанно) замените все на латинские буквы и все будет работать=)
в MyClass ob = new MyClass();
и ob.beta = 88;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в строке `MyClass оb = new MyClass();`, 'ob' в неверной кодировке. переименуйте из в верной кодировке и на английском. А так же в строке `оb.beta = 88;` тоже переименуйте переменную 'ob'.

Comment: Благодарю краснея. Видимо ту строчку и копирнул из pdf для ускорения набора.

Answer (score 2):

*int gamma; // .тип доступа по умолчанию (по сути, public)*

нет не public, по умолчанию package

код рабочий, просто у вас что-то с переменной ob
попробуйте ее скопировать от туда, где объявляете 
и вставить ее во всех остальных случаях

просто даже если символы похожи, то у них может быть разная кодировка
сравните **ob** написано по английски и **ob** первая буква в русской раскладке